# Extending a dataset based on multiple IDs in a column

Tags: python, r, data-science

It's a data-wrangling problem, issue with a query. I have a dataset, and each row does not represent 1 sample but contains one column which has a list of ID's. For example, You have 3 columns: age, sex & ID's. You could have one row: `28, M, 'ID209,ID208'`.

Are there easy ways to extend this data-set such that I have one row per ID number? I'm working with R or Python.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to provide a sample of the data for us to help though. If you're using R, see [here for creating a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4421870)

Comment: R solution: `library(tidyverse); df %>% mutate(id = stringr::str_split(id, “,”)) %>% unnest(id)`

Comment: thanks, unnest was really the function i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the cleanest Python solution, but it should get you started.

This assumes that you have split rows down into a list of this form: `[age, sex, 'ids']`. This code should be easy to modify to fit your actual row format, but this should be sufficient to get you started.

```
new_rows = []
for row in dataset:
    id1, id2 = row[2].split(',')
    new_rows.append([row[0], row[1], id1])
    new_rows.append([row[0], row[1], id2])

print(new_rows)
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

An R solution using `tidytext`. Assuming that values in column `ids` are comma-separated:

```
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)

df1 <- data.frame(age = 28, 
                  sex = "M", 
                  ids = "ID209,ID208", 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1 %>% 
  unnest_tokens(id, ids, token = str_split, pattern = ",", to_lower = FALSE)

    age sex    id
1    28   M ID209
1.1  28   M ID208
```